# How to fill an array/list separately in Java?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, crud

I have the class  "1". In that class I defined the variables "name" "phone number" and "ID". I defined all the sets and gets methods and the constructor for those variables.

In the class "2" I want to fill from the consol those variables. That will be the fist "option" of my **CRUD**, so everytime the user selects opcion=1, the system has to let add separately each of those variables. I know I have to use Array List but I haven't been able to do it successfully. This is an example of the code. CAPITAL LETTERS code is where I'm stuck. Thanks.

```
------First Class---------
package VV;

public class 1 
{

    private String name;
    private String phone_number;
    private String id;

    public 1(String name, String phone_number, String id)
    {this.name=name;
    this.phone_number=phone_number;
    this.id=id;
    }
    
    public String getName() 
    {   return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) 
    {   this.name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone_number() 
    {   return phone_number;
    }

    public void setPhone_number(String phone_number) 
    {   this.phone_number = phone_number;
    }

    public String getId() 
    {   return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) 
    {   this.id = id;
    }
----------Second class------------
package VV;

     public class 2 
     {
     public 2()
          {"Insert the name of the student:"
           A METHOD TO INSERT THE NAME OF THE STUDENT
           "Insert the phone number of the student:"
            A METHOD TO INSERT THE PHONE NUMBER OF THE STUDENT
           "Insert the ID of the student:"
            A METHOD TO INSERT THE ID OF THE STUDENT
           ..And so on, each time user selects the opcion "add new student"
           (I didn't put the while-case here with all its options to simply)

           }
     }
```

Comment: why are you taking input inside the constructor of that class `2`?

Comment: The "input" will be in another class (3). I put it that way to clarify what kind of method I want to create there. The inputs won't be there in practice.

Comment: Make sure your naming follows [conventions](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions) or you'll find it difficult to read and more difficult to get support

Comment: Why do you need a 2nd class to insert values into the 1st class?  That sounds like methods that should be in the 1st class to begin with

Comment: Based on the context, I guess the input should be in main operating class. An object of first class should be declared and initialized and according to the input of the users, the fields can be set

Comment: @Nexevis All can be in the same class, I agree. Nevertheless, the huge business is that I don't know to create a method to fill the array variable-to-variable, from the console.

Comment: @Rooney Moba Use a `Scanner`?  There should be a lot of information available online on this subject.

Comment: Nexevis I did. But all the videos I found, are examples where they fill arrays directly in the code. Something like: objectX= new Object("Andrew", "+1546161","the id number"). I didn't find videos where they fill it with the inputs of the user (readLines).

Comment: @RooneyMoka I recommend you should probably go and read up again how constrcutors work because your last comments kind of display a misunderstanding of how they work and how you call them. A constructor requires you to pass the variables it needs to it, If that variable is a string you can either directly declare it inline line `new Object("MyString")` or you can pass a String variable like `String myStringVar;` and then do `new Object(myStringVar)`. All you have to do is ask the user for input then save that input in variables and pass them to your constructor.

Comment: Did you try compiling your code? `1` and `2` are not valid class names.

Comment: @AlexRudenko I put those name to make the example as simple as possible. On my netbeans the first class is "Def_va" and the second one is "Def_met".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually don't know why you need that second class's constructor to take input from user and fill the fields of first class.

What I understood from the whole discussion is, you need to set the variables of the class by taking user input, and you need a dynamic way to take that input and set the values.

**First way:**

Well, this is a bit dynamic. You can use `reflection` to access all the variables of a class, and you can set their values dynamically.

First of all, create a default constructor in the `first` class. Then In the main class/whereever you want to take the input from user, create an object of first class and initialize it with default constructor. Then use reflection to work with individual fields, taking input from users and setting the values in the fields. This way doesn't require to know what fields are there to take input from user explicitly. Remember, you can use this method only if there's no problem to expose the names of the variables to the end user. I used only String input as you have only strings in the first class as variables. You need that `field.setAccessible(true)` if the variables are private. So, let's see the code in the main class/where you'll call the function to take user input:

```
Field[] arrayOfFields = Student.class.getDeclaredFields();
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
Student student = new Student();
for (Field field : arrayOfFields) {
    try {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        System.out.println("Please enter the Student " + field.getName());
        field.set(student, sc.nextLine());
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

That sets the fields accordingly.

**Second Way:**

If you know the variables you need to initialize the objects, just use scanner to scan them one by one from the user console input and initialize the object:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String id,name,phone_number;
System.out.println("Please enter the Student ID:");
id = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter the Student Name:");
name = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter the Student Phone Number:");
phone_number = sc.nextLine();
Student student = new Student(id, name, phone_number);
```

Simple as that.

Comment: Yes! This is perfect! I didn't know that scanner, method. I'm still an amateur. Thank you!